# How to model a jagged cave?

Tags: modeling, particles

How I recreate/model a cave that looks exactly like this (?):

[image]

I have tried using particle systems but it ended up looking ugly as the particles overlapped way too much and could not be given an individual, unique offset as seen in the image.Am I missing something regarding the particles?

Also, I'm open to any other suggestion to go about this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the question was on particles here's my take on it.

Start with a cylinder.

[image]

Subdivide it a number of times but make it somehow irregular with a fractal:

[image]

Then create some cuboid object (I put it on a different layer so that is out of the way...)

[image]

Then on the cylinder create a particle system.

Make the start and end frame 1 (so that all of particles are present on frame 1)

Use the cuboid object as the render object.

For rotation select the axis that makes sense depending on how your object is placed (in this case, the object X axis works for me), and set the random rotation to Zero.

Then give the render object some variation on size.

Optionally you can disable the emitter so that only the cuboids show on the render and not the original cylinder.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Giving the particles a bit of randomness might make them more interesting.

[image]

Comment: your solution gives me a part fo my answer and the solution above yours gives me the rest, now I'm conflicted whom to attribute it to XD

Answer (score 6):

You could achieve an approximate result through a *Remesh* modifier.

[image]

Add cylinder object, rotate and scale it to make it elongated and subdivide accordingly. Erase the end faces.

[image: Cylinder]

On top of it add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier set to *Simple*, then a *Displace* modifier.

Set the displace amount to a high value like 1 (depending on the size of your object) and add a new texture.

Switch texture type to *Musgrave* or similar and increase the size so the deformation forms big lumps (as opposed to small frequency noise).

[image: Displace]

Now add a *Remesh* modifier to the object set to *Blocks*. Adjust the *Octree Depth* to a high enough value to generate desired sized blocks.

You can now add another *Subdivision Surface* modifier set to *Simple* on top of it followed by another *Displace* with a new *Musgrave* texture.

Seth both the *Displace Distance* value and *Texture Size* to small values to generate small distortions. Adjust accordingly

[image]

Comment: your solution gives me a part fo my answer and the solution under yours gives me the rest, now I'm conflicted whom to attribute it to XD

Comment: Don't worry about it, if both answers helped you then just upvote them. Marking as accepted is optional

Answer (score 2):

Start with a circle, make faces. Extrude and then <kbd>S</kbd> to make the section closest to you wider.

Delete faces from both ends. Then add round loop cuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) to the inside of the object. Next, grab faces and extrude inward inside the object.

Start with the bigger pieces extruding a few faces at a time. Use <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> on the extruded faces to add complexity.

Add vertices and other loop cuts until you get the desired results.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This answer would be a lot easier to follow if you added a few example screenshots

Comment: How do I upload images?

Comment: While editing a question there is an insert image button at the toolbar. If you press it a dialog with builtin upload options will pop up. You may not have enough reputation to upload a lot of pictures.

Comment: Nice job, keep it up